# Run a single method in a TestCase class

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
class TestVehicle(TestCase):

    def test_speed(self):
        #checks for speed

    def test_fuel(self):
        #checks fuel quantity
```

I have the above test class with two test methods, but while testing I want to run *only one* of the two methods. How can I achieve this using

```
unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running single test from unittest.TestCase via command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971735/running-single-test-from-unittest-testcase-via-command-line)

Comment: @Lutz I am not trying to achieve this from command line ,I have a helper class where I create the test suit and execute using unittest.TextTestRunner

Answer (score 0):

You can give the function name too:

```
unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName('TestVehicle.test_speed')
```

This would only run the `test_speed` test.