# Run a single test via a command line when tests are located within a sibling folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a folder structure:

```
app/
|
|-src/
| |
| |-Code.py
|
|-tests/
  |
  |-__init__.py
  |-test_Code.py
```

I run my tests by issuing a command:

```
app$ python3 -m unittest discover
```

And as a result all my tests from `test_Code.py` file are run.

I would like to run a single test from `test_Code.py` file.

The contents of 'test_Code.py' are:

```
import unittest
from src.Code import Code

class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Code1(self):
        ...

    def test_Code2(self):
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

There is a question about running a single test: [Running single test from unittest.TestCase via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971735/running-single-test-from-unittest-testcase-via-command-line).

The answer given is:

> ```
> python testMyCase.py MyCase.testItIsHot
> ```

which in my case would be (I think):

```
app$ python3 tests/test_Code.py TestCase1.test_Code1
```

Unfortunately this results in an error:

> ImportError: No module named 'src'

There has been a comment that the proposed approach does not work, should the tests be in a subdirectory. A resolution is proposed:

> `python test/testMyCase.py test.MyCase.testItIsHot`

I therefore try:

```
app$ python3 tests/test_Code.py test_Code.TestCase1.test_Code1
```

Which results in the same error.

I have also tried, among a couple of different things:

```
app$ python3 -m unittest tests/test_Code.py test_Code.TestCase1.test_Code1
```

But this runs all the tests.

The question is then:
how to run a single test via a command line when tests are located within a sibling folder?

Comment: At what level are you running the tests from? At app level? Is "app" a python module or a simple module?

Comment: @VivekAkupatni They are run at `app` level. What do you mean by module or simple module? There is no `__init__.py` in `app` folder, if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry I meant directory or python module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
python -m unittest -v tests.test_Code.TestCase1.test_Code1
```

Assuming that src is a also a module