# Why is using the verbose flag necessary to run a specific unittest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

From the question on [running a single test via command line when tests are located within a sibling folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475638), the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484454/3621940) suggests using the `-v` option alongside the module name and test name to run a specific test.

Why does the `-v` option make this work? Specifying the module name and the test name makes sense since it corresponds to the [unittest documnetation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) and obviously you need to specify which test to run. However, from what I can tell, the `-v` option  corresponds to verbose output which shouldn't change the tests that the unittest module runs.

Apologies in advance if I've missed something obvious here.

Comment: Have you tried without `-v`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Without the `-v` option, it runs all tests in the `tests` directory instead of the specified test.

Comment: Can you show us both complete command lines (with and without `-v`)? This sounds quite strange...

Comment: Thanks for the comment about checking out the command lines. See the my answer for info about what was going wrong when I did my test.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this wasn't working was because of a pretty obvious, but stupid, error on my part .

tldr; Use the full command line to run the tests (e.g. `python3 -m unittest tests.module_name.TestClass.test_func`) or if you're using a bash function, make sure the function accepts other arguments.

I had setup a bash function called `run_tests` to run unittests and I was trying to specify the module name and test name after calling that method. I.e. I had the following in .bash_profile:

```sh
run_tests ()
{
    python3 -m unittest
}
```

and on the terminal, I did:

```
run_tests tests.module_name.TestClass.test_func
```

Since the bash function was not setup to accept arguments, the specific test I wanted to run wasn't actually being passed as an argument to unittest.

Obviously, using `-v` makes no difference if you use the `run_tests` function to try and run a specific test.

When I tested with the `-v` option, I used the full command `python3 -m unittest -v tests.module_name.TestClass.test_func` which is why I thought the `-v` option made it work. To test whether the `-v` option actually worked, I was lazy and ran `run_tests tests.module_name.TestClass.test_func` again since it was in my shell history instead of typing out the full command, which is what caused this confusion.