# Test a specified one of functions in one TestCase

Tags: python

I am learning algorithms in leetcodes and usually have multiple testing in one TestCase

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Tesing threeSum.py Solution class.
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution()
    def test_1(self):
    def test_2(self):
    ...
   def test_3(self):
```

When I want to test one particular function, then have to comment others out.

Is there a solution to test a specified function in one TestCase?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971735/running-single-test-from-unittest-testcase-via-command-line

Comment: I cannot believe there exist such a powerful tool as unittest, amazing @9769953

Comment: Then you haven't seen [pytest](https://pytest.org) yet, which is my current go-to testing tool (not built-in, but pretty much standard and easy to install).